# Determine size within each each group having the same value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have `dataframe` like so,

```
ID,CLASS_ID,ACTIVE
1,123,0
2,123,0
3,456,1
4,123,0
5,456,1
11,123,1
18,123,0
7,456,0
19,123,0
8,456,1
```

I'm trying to get the cumulative counts of the `CLASS_ID` having same value for `ACTIVE`. In case of the dataframe given above, `CLASS_ID` is continuously having `ACTIVE` as `0`, until the 4th record post which next value is 1. So up until 4th record, count should be 3. This process has to be continued and the count has to be resetted every time value of `ACTIVE` changes for the `CLASS_ID` The expected output is as follows..

```
ID,CLASS_ID,ACTIVE,ACTIVE_COUNT
1,123,0,3
2,123,0,3
3,456,1,2
4,123,0,3
5,456,1,2
11,123,1,1
18,123,0,2
7,456,0,1
19,123,0,2
8,456,1,1
```

I tried using `df.groupby(..).transform(..)` but its not working out for me. Could someone help me out a bit?

Comment: Do you mean the third instead of the fourth record? Still not really understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby`:

```
ind = df.groupby('CLASS_ID').ACTIVE.apply(
    lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()
)
df['ACTIVE_COUNT'] = df.groupby(['CLASS_ID', ind]).ACTIVE.transform('count')

df
   ID  CLASS_ID  ACTIVE  ACTIVE_COUNT
0   1       123       0             3
1   2       123       0             3
2   3       456       1             2
3   4       123       0             3
4   5       456       1             2
5  11       123       1             1
6  18       123       0             2
7   7       456       0             1
8  19       123       0             2
9   8       456       1             1
```

---

**Details**
First, create an indicator column marking rows with the same value per group:

```
ind = df.groupby('CLASS_ID').ACTIVE.apply(
    lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()
)
ind

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    3
7    2
8    3
9    3
Name: ACTIVE, dtype: int64
```

We then use `ind` as a grouper argument to `df.groupby` along with "CLASS_ID", and then compute the size of each group using `transform`.

```
df.groupby(['CLASS_ID', ind]).ACTIVE.transform('count')

0    3
1    3
2    2
3    3
4    2
5    1
6    2
7    1
8    2
9    1
Name: ACTIVE, dtype: int64
```